# Mnemonics in ComboBox control

Tags: winforms, combobox

I have inherited a ComboBox control mainly to create a different visual look. However, this behaviour where the ampersand is being turned into a shortcut (letter after is underlined) in the text field of the control has me stumped. I know this feature exists on Label controls and it can be turned off but here? How can I turn it off?

[image: ComboBox appearance]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit. I've used Graphics.DrawString for drawing items and TextRenderer.DrawText for textbox portion of control. The former by default doesn't draw mnemonics and the latter one does. In both methods this feature can be turned on or off.